# jQuery toggleClass for multiple elements with loop and var

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I've got multiple elements on .list1 and .list2 uls, .list2 is not visible and elements from .list1 triggers elements from .list2. I do not know how many elements there will be so I would like to use loop for some jQuery code with click event. But the loops does not work. What am I doing wrong?

[JS Fiddile here](http://jsfiddle.net/rgD92/10/)

```
<ul class="list1">
<li class="opt1">option1</li>
<li class="opt2">option2</li>
<li class="opt3">option3</li>
<li class="opt4">option4</li>
<li class="opt5">option5</li>
```

```
<ul class="list2">
<li class="opt1">option1</li>
<li class="opt2">option2</li>
<li class="opt3">option3</li>
<li class="opt4">option4</li>
<li class="opt5">option5</li>
```

```
for (var x = 1; x <= 5; x++){
  $(".list1 li.opt" + x).click(function() {
      $(".list2 li").removeClass("selected");   
      $(".list2 li.opt" + x).addClass("selected");
  });
}
```

Comment: class name can be of same to make everything easy!

Comment: Reason why orginal code failed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: If you know that you can have multiple chained lists, you maybe transform them in a select and use this http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained ( only if you know some stuff will go far away and you might lose control of them )

Answer (score 2):

Try to write a `single event` for this purpose do not go for a `for` loop, and make use of the `.index()` to grab the related element from list-2

```
$('.list1 li').click(function () {
    $('.list2 li').removeClass("selected").eq($(this).index()).addClass("selected");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rgD92/12/)

Comment: So, that simple, no need for loop? Thank you. But why loop was not working?

Comment: @Ecnelis, because inside `click` event handler `x` equals to 6, not to current value.

Comment: @Ecnelis That's because of false scoping. We need to create a scope  per iteration to over that issue. But that's a kind of advanced concept, probably you need to go through some online topics related to scoping and closure to get a good grip over it.

Comment: Just to mention: even though `index()` solves problems like this, it still will be better to use some `data` attribute for mapping elements from one list to another.

Comment: @Regent But personally, i hate hard coding stuffs.. :\

Comment: looks complicated ;) Thanks.

Comment: @Ecnelis it's actually the shortest and simple solution. You can split code into several lines to make it looks simplier. I think this answer is worth to be accepted, isn't it?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy well, if these `li` are generated dymanically, and somewhy `.list2` will be formed in another order (or one element from list will be lost), this will crash the whole solution. Yes, it will probably never happen, but nevertheless basing on element's attribute, not on element's position, sounds more reliable to me. But, of course, I vote up for this answer as correct one without HTML restructuring.